# Document object not getting created

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a web page through Javascript code and parse it to get the value of certain element using XPath. The code I have written to create a document object reurns {location: null} for every URL. The code is given below:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        req.open('GET', 'https://www.someurl.com', false);  
    req.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=windows-1251'); // for Cyrillic     
        req.send(null);
        if(req.status == 200) { 
           //console.log(req.responseText);
           var xmlString = req.responseText;
           var parser = new DOMParser();
           var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml"); 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(xmlDoc)); // it outputs {"location": null}

        }
```

Please let me know if I am mistaking something.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the asynchronous behaviour of `XMLHttpRequest()`. You are getting null because `req.send(null)` is an asynchronous call and the response will be handled separately by an event handler.

For more information on asynchronous behaviour, please refer to [Asynchronous Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)

Basically, you need to attach an event handler to handle the response of `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // do your thing here
    }
};
```

This is done before your `req.send(null);`